# How to make a yes and no options in the console in c#

Tags: c#, console-application

I making a text adventure game and I'm stuck with making a y/n option.

This is my code. BTW I'm to new to coding like one night new.

```
Console.WriteLine("Are You Ready For The Day My Lord [y/n]");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Sorry if this too easy.

Comment: Do you only want to check if the Player inputs "y" or "n"?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with someting like this

```
        Console.WriteLine("Are You Ready For The Day My Lord [y/n]");
        string yesNo = Console.ReadLine(); //get the answer

        if(yesNo == "y") //check the answer
          Console.WriteLine("You are ready."); //write something for option y
        else
          Console.WriteLine("You are NOT ready."); //write something for other option
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can be your case

```cs
ConsoleKeyInfo k = Console.ReadKey();
        
if (k.Key.ToString() == "y")
{
    // do what you need for yes
}
else 
{
    // presses something other then Y
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use string.Equals to compare strings so something like this should work properly:

```
Console.WriteLine("Are You Ready For The Day My Lord [y/n]");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

if(string.Equals(userInput, "y"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You answered yes");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You answered no");
}
```

This if you want only "y" or "n"

Comment: That's rather more long-winded than using `==`, and for no benefit that I can see...

Comment: This variant could be interesting if you need case-independent comparison like  `string.Equals(userInput, "y", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know that, I will remember it. I f you want to edit my answer maybe he can find it useful too though.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are going to be doing this a lot, so perhaps wrap these sort of things up in a helper class

```
public static class Prompt
{
    public bool GetYesNo(string input)
    {
        Console.Writeline(input + " [y/n]");
        var result = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        if(result == "y") return true;
        if(result == "n") return false;
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
        return GetYesNo(input);
    }
}
```

Then in your console app:

```
var ready = Prompt.GetYesNo("Are You Ready For The Day My Lord");
if(ready)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code for it.

```
Console.WriteLine("Are You Ready For The Day My Lord [y/n]");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

if(string.Equals(userInput, "y"))
{
Console.WriteLine("You answered yes");
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("You answered no");
}
```

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Console.WriteLine("Are You Ready For The Day My Lord [y/n]");
string currOption = Console.ReadLine();
if (currOption == "Y" || currOption == "y"){
   Console.WriteLine("You answered yes");
}
else if(currOption == "N" || currOption == "n"){
   Console.WriteLine("You answered no");
}
else{
   Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
}
```

Hope it works!